# Is there any way to export intents for watson conversation?

Tags: watson-conversation

You can import intents for watson conversation in CSV format, but there doesn't appear to be a way to export them (and really, I'm looking for the exact format that is needed to import them, but I would also like to know how to export).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to export. The best way to do it is to go to your project menu, and export as JSON.

[image: Download As JSON menu option]

After that, if you check in the JSON file, you will find the questions and intents. You can also get access to your entities this way as well (easier way to import entities).

example:

```
  "intents":[{
      "intent":"conditions",
      "created":"2016-08-17T12:52:08.806Z",
      "examples":[{
          "text":"Are the winds dangerous?",
          "created":"2016-08-17T12:52:08.859Z"
        },
        {
          "text":"Are we expecting sunny conditions?",
          "created":"2016-08-17T12:52:08.859Z"
        },
        {
          "text":"How much rain will fall today?",
          "created":"2016-08-17T12:52:08.859Z"
        },
        {
          "text":"How much snow are we expecting?",
          "created":"2016-08-17T12:52:08.859Z"
        },
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh of course I find the answer in the official documentation seconds after posting this question:

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/intent_ovw.shtml

Essentially, it's a big list of:

```
example, intent-name
...
exampleN, intent-nameN
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtlety here; the JSON download does provide all of the configuration details and can be edited programmatically, but when you upload the edited JSON to use changes, it creates a new workspace with the same name as the one you downloaded from. I'm too new to know if there's a way around this or if it even matters, but just thought I'd share. :)