# Is there a programmatic way to export intents for Watson Conversation?

Tags: watson-conversation

I am aware you can go to the Watson Conversation interface, right click on a workspace, and download the JSON of a workspace, which contains the intents, as it says here: [Is there any way to export intents for watson conversation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080543/is-there-any-way-to-export-intents-for-watson-conversation/39708599#39708599)

However, I need to write a program/script to do this automatically. An API method for this would be great, but I did not find any method exposed in the [API documentation](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#methods). My question is different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635955/bluemix-watson-conversation-api-to-manage-intents-entities), because I could try a workaround and not use the API, like doing a GET to the download link, but I could not deal with the SSO authentication.

How can I download the workspace JSON programmatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluemix Watson Conversation API to manage intents, entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635955/bluemix-watson-conversation-api-to-manage-intents-entities)

Comment: Thanks, James. Just edited my question to explain how it's different than the suggested duplicate.

Comment: The download link in the UI is not intended to be used programmatically. I guess you could try something like Selenium but the correct way to programmatically export workspaces will be to use the public API once it's been updated. Unfortunately I cannot give you an ETA but updating the API is a high priority.

Comment: I agree that the download link is not the best solution. It would just be a workaround while we don't have the proper API method. I am looking forward to seeing the API updates and glad to hear it's a high priority. Thanks a lot, James.

Comment: Watson Conversation recently released APIs on Intents: see here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#intents

Comment: Thanks, Brian! I marked this question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The /workspaces endpoint was recently announced and might meet your need.  Take a look here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#get_workspace  Look at EntityExportResponse.

Comment: Yes, as it says here, we can now get the intents of a workspace. Thank you!

```"(...) If the export parameter is true, the return data also includes all workspace content (such as intents, entities, and dialog nodes) in JSON format. "```